# Can't login to Symfony with admin credentials

Tags: symfony

I am stepping into an older codebase that I am largely unresponsible for.  So I apologize in advance if there are gaps in my knowledge.

We have a Symfony app running that *used* to work but has been very weird lately, with all sorts of bugs.  Not the least of which is that I can no longer log in with the credentials as described in security.yml.

Here is the security.yml file:

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin:
                    password: DefinitelyTheRealPassword
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
          login_path: login
          check_path: login
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

access_control:
    - { path: ^/refresh, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

When I try to login as "admin" with the actual password in our security.yml file (which is unhashed, plain text, etc., nothing weird about it), I simply get the message "Invalid credentials."

Our security controller is taken straight from the Symfony example docs, so I don't know if it's worth posting.

The strangest part is that it *did* work before, and now it doesn't.  Checking out older commits where the app was working doesn't help either.  I have noticed that there is no "users" table in the db, but since the login info is in_memory, I wouldn't think it matters.

I'm happy to post more code if there's anything that seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your check_path. Try this instead:

```
main:
  anonymous: true
  form_login:
    login_path: login
    check_path: login_check
  logout:
    path:       logout
    target:     login
```

and verify your routing.yml

```
login_check:
    path: /login_check
```

Comment: Does something actually need to exist at the path /login_check?

Comment: Symfony will catch the visitor's request on route login_check, and manage the authentication itself.